# How on earth does he debug a running application like this, and more importantly, how can I?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, remote-debugging

### "Debugception!"

You may notice that within the first [15 seconds of this YouTube video (from 1:01:01 to 1:01:16)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhN35bGvM8c&t=1h01m01s), Markus Persson (aka "Notch", creator of Minecraft) has somehow managed to save/update an application and attach a debugger to it **while it was already under the process of being debugged**, supposedly all with a simple keyboard shortcut. The previously coded application somehow magically became the newly edited one, and seemingly ***without*** relaunching it or spawning a new process... It's possible that this is just some form of locally remote debugging, but something about it just doesn't seem quite right.

I've spent several days Googling and asking around on how he was able to do this, yet to no avail. I've found no such option under Eclipse preferences, and whenever I try to save & debug an already running application, it simply launches a separate instance of the newly updated application, side-by-side with the older, outdated one.

Am I missing something? How was this possible?
How was he able to utilize such an astounding, powerful debugging feature?
Thanks in advance!

### Update

Okay, so this appears to be a standard feature specific to Eclipse.
Coming from a background in NetBeans and Visual Studio, I'm astounded that this doesn't seem to exist elsewhere (or at least in NetBeans!)...

Comment: For Eclipse it's as simple as altering something in the source code and saving after having launched in debugging mode

Comment: This has been a feature of Netbeans for years - it is in the debug menu "Apply code changes".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a built-in feature of Eclipse. If you edit a method while the program is running in debug mode, it will compile the new method, and replace the old method with the new version. If some thread was already running that method, it will jump back to the beginning (AFAIK; this might only happen when the program is paused).

You don't need to re-launch the program or set any special preferences. Just edit and save, and the magic will happen.

Eclipse can't always figure out how to merge your changes into the running program - usually if you changed anything outside a method body (including the method's parameters or return type). In this case, you will get a warning dialog, with the option to stop the program, restart the program or ignore the changes.

Comment: Strangely enough, I've tried doing this already and it didn't change anything in the running application... But I tried it again just now on another project, and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: The Debug view will show a warning of some sort if you've made changes that couldn't be hotswapped.  It depends on what you've changed, and where the code is paused/running at the time - not all changes are compatible.